# Switching to a new tab using browser.pages() in Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, xpath, jquery-selectors, puppeteer

I am trying to do this:

1. Open Google
2. Search "hotels in london"
3. Click on "View 3810 hotels"

---new page opens ---

4. Click on "Learn more" button for the first hotel

---new page opens ---

5. Click on "Prices"

---new page opens ---

6. Scrape some information

I have successfully completed steps 1-4, but I am stuck on step 5 because puppeteer doesn't automatically click on prices. In fact, nothing happens at step 5. I learnt that this is because the "Prices" selector keeps changing which is why I should use page.$(). However, that hasn't helped either.

Here is my code:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    //google.com
    await page.goto("https://google.com");
    await page.type("input.gLFyf.gsfi", "hotels in london");
    await page.keyboard.press("Enter");

    //search results
    await page.waitForSelector(
      "#rso > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > g-more-link > a > div"
    );
    await page.click(
      "#rso > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > g-more-link > a > div"
    );

    //list of hotels
    await page.waitForSelector(
      "#yDmH0d > c-wiz.zQTmif.SSPGKf > div > div.lteUWc > div > c-wiz > div > div.gpcwnc > div.cGQUT > main > div > div.Hkwcrd.Sy8xcb.XBQ4u > c-wiz > div.J6e2Vc > div > div > span > span"
    );

    //click on view prices
    await page.click(
      "#yDmH0d > c-wiz.zQTmif.SSPGKf > div > div.lteUWc > div > c-wiz > div > div.gpcwnc > div.cGQUT > main > div > div.Hkwcrd.Sy8xcb.XBQ4u > c-wiz > div.l5cSPd > c-wiz:nth-child(5) > div > div > div > div.kCsInf.ZJqrAd.qiy8jf > div > div.TPQEac.RCpQOe > a > button > span"
    );

    //get list of open tabs (does not include new tab)
    const pages = await browser.pages();

    //prints 2 although there are 3 tabs
    console.log(pages.length); 

    // get the new page
    const page2 = pages[pages.length - 1]; 
    const url = await page2.evaluate(() => window.location.href);

    //prints url of page with list of hotels
    console.log(url); 

    //takes screen shot of penultimate tab instead of new tab
    await page2.screenshot({ path: "sample.png" }); 

    let providers = 0;

    await browser.close();
    return providers;
  
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
        })()
      .then((resolvedValue) => {
       console.log(resolvedValue);
      })
      .catch((rejectedValue) => {
        console.log(rejectedValue);
      });
```

With navigation, I am able to switch to the new tab but I get a timeout error:

```
TimeoutError: 
Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded
    at C:\Users\Ayesha\Desktop\web_scraping_practice\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\LifecycleWatcher.js:100:111
    at async FrameManager.waitForFrameNavigation (C:\Users\Ayesha\Desktop\web_scraping_practice\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\FrameManager.js:107:23)
    at async Frame.waitForNavigation (C:\Users\Ayesha\Desktop\web_scraping_practice\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\FrameManager.js:298:16)
    at async Page.waitForNavigation (C:\Users\Ayesha\Desktop\web_scraping_practice\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:560:16)
    at async C:\Users\Ayesha\Desktop\web_scraping_practice\loop.js:28:5
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ayesha\Desktop\web_scraping_practice\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:116:19)
    at Page.waitForNavigation (C:\Users\Ayesha\Desktop\web_scraping_practice\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:560:53)
    at Page.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ayesha\Desktop\web_scraping_practice\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:117:27)
    at C:\Users\Ayesha\Desktop\web_scraping_practice\loop.js:28:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  name: 'TimeoutError'
}
undefined

  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ayesha\Desktop\web_scraping_practice\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:116:19)
    at Page.waitForNavigation (C:\Users\Ayesha\Desktop\web_scraping_practice\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:560:53)
    at Page.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ayesha\Desktop\web_scraping_practice\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:117:27)
    at C:\Users\Ayesha\Desktop\web_scraping_practice\loop.js:28:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  name: 'TimeoutError'
}
```

**UPDATE:**
The timeout error went away after modifying page.waitForNavigation() like this:

```
    //click on view prices
    const btn2 = await page.$x('//span[contains(text(),"Learn more")]');
    await Promise.all([
      page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "load" }),
      btn2[0].click(),
    ]);
```

Comment: Your issue is here not related to dynamic selectors, but **the fact in the middle of your scenario you open a new tab** which needs to be handled. Can you modify your questions title according to this? See my answer below with a possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

In headful mode you can see that clicking on *"Learn more"* indeed opens a new page, but this time on a brand new tab. This needs to be handled in its own context, that's why puppeteer doesn't find your elements. Here comes [`browser.pages`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.0.0&show=api-browserpages) to the rescue. With its help you can get the current tabs in an array and by using e.g. the `[2]` index you can control the content of the new tab.

```js
const addBtn = await page.$x('//span[contains(text(), "Learn more")]')
await addBtn[0].click()

await page.waitFor(3000) // just to make sure the new tab is opened
const pages = await browser.pages()
await pages[2].waitForXPath('//*[@id="prices"]/span') // wait for prices section to load
```

The next problem is with this line:

```js
const link = await (await page.$('//*[@id="prices"]/span')).click() // click on "Prices"
```

FYI: when you have a unique id attribute it's better to prefer it over XPath selectors (XPath is rather a worst case scenario when you need to use its dedicated methods like [`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) due to everchanging dynamic selectors, but this element has a static id)

You could fix this line with:

```js
const link = await page.$x('//*[@id="prices"]/span')
await link[0].click() // click on "Prices"
```

Or more simply with:

```js
await page.click('#prices')
```

*Note:* You will need to apply `pages[n]` instead of `page` here as well.

---

### Edit

Try [`await page.waitForNavigation()`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-pagewaitfornavigationoptions) before `browser.pages()` to make sure you have all three tabs are loaded. For me it works without any issues:

```js
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false
    })
    const page = await browser.newPage()

    //google.com
    await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({ 'Accept-Language': 'en-US' })
    await page.goto('https://google.com')
    await page.type('input.gLFyf.gsfi', 'hotels in london')
    await page.keyboard.press('Enter')

    //search results
    await page.waitForXPath('//span[contains(text(),"View ")]')
    const btn1 = await page.$x('//span[contains(text(),"View ")]')
    await btn1[0].click()

    //list of hotels
    await page.waitForXPath('//span[contains(text(),"Learn more")]')

    //click on view prices
    const btn2 = await page.$x('//span[contains(text(),"Learn more")]')
    await btn2[0].click()

    await page.waitForNavigation()

    //get list of open tabs (does not include new tab)
    const pages = await browser.pages()

    //prints 2 although there are 3 tabs
    console.log(pages.length)

    // get the new page
    const page2 = pages[pages.length - 1]
    const url = await page2.evaluate(() => window.location.href)

    //prints url of page with list of hotels
    console.log(url)

    //takes screen shot of penultimate tab instead of new tab
    await page2.screenshot({ path: 'sample.png' })

    let providers = 0

    await browser.close()
```

Output:

```
3
https://www.google.com/travel/hotels/entity/CgoI0uWTwdT7-Y0lEAEaYEFHWklFZ2FXVXZpS2RQNGwyenhic3I5UHhJZEZFVDIwUmNrcTlfNmJUY01adXBZbElTTzE3YmpxclMtdVFNSkREeTlnbGJhTTFXYTEycGlsM1ZwdUdFdkJ4S1hpOXBhXw?g2lb=2502548%2C4258168%2C4270442%2C4306835%2C4308226%2C4317915%2C4322823%2C4328159%2C4344617%2C4358983%2C4367954%2C4371335%2C4401769%2C4403882%2C4414391%2C4416581%2C4418077%2C4421967%2C4270859%2C4284970%2C4291517%2C4412693&hl=hu&gl=hu&un=1&ap=aAE&q=hotels%20in%20london&rp=EN__hZ2wsYS5SxDZ_fO86Oyr1kUQq9TZmpT3hYhnENb4j4D5sOPDqQE4AUAASAKiAR1Mb25kb24sIEVneWVzw7xsdCBLaXLDoWx5c8OhZw&ictx=1&sa=X&ei=9r82X8HlKoaJgAf1pqfAAQ&utm_campaign=sharing&utm_medium=link&utm_source=htls&hrf=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
0
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work either. With browser.pages(), I don't get an error but my program keeps running and puppeteer doesn't interact with the new tab.

Comment: You might need `pages[1]` or `pages[3]` (it depends on how many tabs are opened, I just gave an example). You can debug the current element of the array with the following script: `const url = await page.evaluate(() => window.location.href);
console.log(url);` You can be sure that this is needed, it is required to switch tab when your script opens new tabs.

Comment: Also, you need to use: `pages[n]` on the hotel `/entity/` page all the time (for the `click()` and so on). So please align to the examples I gave above: we won't write your script line-by-line instead of you just giving the answers how you can make it work ;)

Comment: Hello, browser.pages() works but I am still not able to access the newly opened tab. For debugging purposes, I checked the URL of the last tab contained in pages array and it seems that the new tab isn't returned by browser.pages at all. I am very confused at this point and I don't really know how to fix this error.

Comment: Basically, browser.pages should return an array of 3 tabs, but it returns 2 tabs instead.

Comment: hi, can you update your question above with the current code you are trying? You might use `browser.pages()` too early or there is another circumstance differs.

Comment: I have updated my code. I have also tried to debug the code using pages.length and by taking screen shots of all tab contained in pages. While pages[0] and pages[1] are defined, pages[2] returns undefined, although it should point to new tab.                                               You can perhaps try running my code to get a better idea of the error.

Comment: I also tried using page.waitFor(3000) right before browser.pages() but that didn't work either

Comment: I used `await page.waitForNavigation() ` now, it works for me, see the attached output. Also I replaced the long, dynamic selectors to XPath contains methods, so they won't break frequently.

Comment: I pasted your code and I am now able to switch to the new tab but I am getting a timeout error due to navigation :(

Comment: I have pasted the error below the code in the question

Comment: I suppose you have a bit slower network connection, you can increase the timeout from the default 30 seconds (but it is very suspicious that it even exceeds that): `await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded', timeout: 100000 })`

Comment: the new timout is also exceeded. Basically, once puppeteer switches to the new tab, it just stays there and then times out. Is there an alternative to navigation?

Comment: Update: I was able to get rid of the error by using Promise.all (changes made in original code). Thank you so very much theDavidBarton for patiently helping me fix my code!!

Comment: Hi, so my program works with one tab, but I actually want to open multiple tabs one by one and scrape information from each. I am able to do that but I get a timeout error after opening 1-2 tabs. I have made a new post for this error on StackOverflow and it would be really helpful if you could help me out. Here's the link to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63423958/looping-through-an-array-of-links-gives-navigation-timeout-error-puppeteer

Answer (score 0):

Try the parent element:

```
await page.click('#prices')
```

Comment: I replaced the line before '//do something' with this, but it isn't working either. I'm getting the error: "no node found for '#prices' ". I got a timeout error when I passed the argument of page.$ to click()

Comment: You might have to wait for it first.

Comment: I did    await page.waitForXPath('//*[@id="prices"]/span');

Comment: I do wait for it : await page.waitForXPath('//*[@id="prices"]/span'); But it doesn't work. I get a timeout error iwith the message: TimeoutError: waiting for XPath "//*[@id="prices"]/span" failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded

Comment: what do you think could be causing the timeout error?