# Looping through an array of links gives navigation timeout error - puppeteer

Tags: navigation, timeout, puppeteer

I have an array of button elements that I want to click one by one and do this for each new tab that opens:

1. Scrape some information and store in an array called 'providers'
2. Close that tab

While I am able to do this, I keep getting a timeout error due to the navigation component that I have used before browser.pages(). If I remove the component, I get another timeout error. Also, every time I run the program, it runs into a timeout error after a different number of iterations of the button array. Here is my code:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    //google.com
    await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({ "Accept-Language": "en-US" });
    await page.goto("https://google.com");
    await page.type("input.gLFyf.gsfi", "hotels in london");
    await page.keyboard.press("Enter");

    //search results
    await page.waitForXPath('//span[contains(text(),"View ")]');
    const btn1 = await page.$x('//span[contains(text(),"View ")]');
    await btn1[0].click();

    //list of hotels
    await page.waitForXPath('//span[contains(text(),"Learn more")]');

    let hotels = [];
    
    //buttons array that contains a list of buttons
    let buttons = await page.$x("//button[contains(., 'View prices')]");
 
    //prints a different value each time the program is run
    console.log(buttons.length);
 
    //looping through buttons array
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {

      //i = 1 or 0 when program hangs 
      console.log("got here " + I);

      //*******************************cause of timeout error******************************************

      await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
      await Promise.all([
        page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "load", timeout: 0 }),
        buttons[i].click(),
      ]);

      //***********************************************************************************************

      //getting all open tabs in an array
      const pages = await browser.pages();
      const page2 = pages[pages.length - 1];
      console.log(pages.length);

      //newly opened tab, sometimes program hangs before opening a new tab
      await page2
        .waitForSelector(
          "#prices > c-wiz > div > div.G86l0b > div > div > div > div > div > section > div.Hkwcrd.q9W60.A5WLXb.fLClSe > c-wiz > div > div > span > div > div > div > div > div > a > div > div.cFdfnb > div > span.mK0tQb > span",
          { timeout: 30000 }
        )
        .catch(() => console.log("Class doesn't exist!"));

      /*-----------------scraping information on new tab ----------------------------------*/

      console.log("going to start collecting providers");
      let providers = await page2.evaluate(() => {
        let data = [];
        let elements = document.querySelectorAll(
          "#prices > c-wiz > div > div.G86l0b > div > div > div > div > div > section > div.Hkwcrd.q9W60.A5WLXb.fLClSe > c-wiz > div > div > span > div > div > div > div > div > a > div > div.cFdfnb > div > span.mK0tQb > span"
        );
        for (var element of elements) data.push(element.textContent);
        return data;
      });
      console.log(providers.length);
      console.log("all done");
      console.log(providers);
      hotels.push(providers);

      //closing the new tab
      page2.close();
    }
    
    await browser.close();
    return hotels;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})()
  .then((resolvedValue) => {
    console.log(resolvedValue);
  })
  .catch((rejectedValue) => {
    console.log(rejectedValue);
  });
```

To get rid of the error, I used timeout: 0 and setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0), but now the program just freezes. Here's the error that I was getting before I disabled timeout getting:

```
TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded
    at C:\Users\Me\Desktop\web_scraping_practice\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\LifecycleWatcher.js:100:111
    at async FrameManager.waitForFrameNavigation (C:\Users\Me\Desktop\web_scraping_practice\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\FrameManager.js:107:23)
    at async Frame.waitForNavigation (C:\Users\Me\Desktop\web_scraping_practice\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\FrameManager.js:298:16)
    at async Page.waitForNavigation (C:\Users\Me\Desktop\web_scraping_practice\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:560:16)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async C:\Users\Me\Desktop\web_scraping_practice\backend.js:41:7
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Me\Desktop\web_scraping_practice\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:116:19)
    at Page.waitForNavigation (C:\Users\Me\Desktop\web_scraping_practice\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:560:53)
    at Page.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Me\Desktop\web_scraping_practice\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:117:27)
    at C:\Users\Me\Desktop\web_scraping_practice\backend.js:42:14
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  name: 'TimeoutError'
}
undefined
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Tried running your code, it appears that it'd be wise to hard-code Chromium locale if you're searching for spans by their content, as in my browser they weren't in English. But I tweaked it a bit, managed to open a tab with hotel details. The problem is this selector:

```
$("#prices > c-wiz > div > div.G86l0b > div > div > div > div > div > section > div.Hkwcrd.q9W60.A5WLXb.fLClSe > c-wiz > div > div > span > div > div > div > div > div > a > div > div.cFdfnb > div > span.mK0tQb > span");
```

This thing renders `null`, unfortunately. I believe these set of classes `div.Hkwcrd.q9W60.A5WLXb.fLClSe` is generated dynamically. Not sure what information you actually want to extract, but I'd try looking for DOM elements by this `data-click-type` attribute. In my case it yields:

```
document.querySelectorAll("div[data-click-type='283']");
NodeList(18) [div.YPrvOd, div.YPrvOd, div.YPrvOd, div.YPrvOd, div.YPrvOd, div.YPrvOd, div.YPrvOd, div.YPrvOd, div.YPrvOd, div.YPrvOd, div.YPrvOd, div.YPrvOd, div.YPrvOd, div.YPrvOd, div.YPrvOd, div.YPrvOd, div.YPrvOd, div.YPrvOd]
```

which appears to be type of the room (Superior Double Room etc.). '268' click-type seems to be the website with hotels (booking, hotels.com etc.)

Below code:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    //google.com
    await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({ "Accept-Language": "en-US" });
    await page.goto("https://google.com");
    await page.type("input.gLFyf.gsfi", "hotels in london");
    await page.keyboard.press("Enter");

    //search results
    await page.waitForXPath('//span[contains(text(),"View ")]');
    const btn1 = await page.$x('//span[contains(text(),"View ")]');
    await btn1[0].click();

    //list of hotels
    await page.waitForXPath('//span[contains(text(),"Learn more")]');

    let hotels = [];

    //buttons array that contains a list of buttons
    let buttons = await page.$x("//button[contains(., 'View prices')]");

    //prints a different value each time the program is run
    console.log(buttons.length);

    //looping through buttons array
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {

      //i = 1 or 0 when program hangs
      console.log("got here " + i);

      //*******************************cause of timeout error******************************************

      await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
      await Promise.all([
        page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "load", timeout: 0 }),
        buttons[i].click(),
      ]);

      //***********************************************************************************************

      //getting all open tabs in an array
      const pages = await browser.pages();
      const page2 = pages[pages.length - 1];
      console.log(pages.length);

      //newly opened tab, sometimes program hangs before opening a new tab
      await page2
        .waitForSelector(
          "span[data-click-type='268']",
          { timeout: 30000 }
        )
        .catch(() => console.log("Class doesn't exist!"));

      /*-----------------scraping information on new tab ----------------------------------*/

      console.log("going to start collecting providers");
      let providers = await page2.evaluate(() => {
        let data = [];
        let elements = document.querySelectorAll(
          "span[data-click-type='268']"
        );
        for (var element of elements) data.push(element.textContent);
        return data;
      });
      console.log(providers.length);
      console.log("all done");
      console.log(providers);
      hotels.push(providers);

      //closing the new tab
      page2.close();
    }

    await browser.close();
    return hotels;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})()
  .then((resolvedValue) => {
    console.log(resolvedValue);
  })
  .catch((rejectedValue) => {
    console.log(rejectedValue);
  });
```

Renders the following in my case:

```
(node:16816) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
12
got here 0
3
going to start collecting providers
16
all done
[ 'Booking.com',
  'Tripadvisor.com',
  'Agoda',
  'Hotels.com',
  'Booking.com',
  'Tripadvisor.com',
  'Agoda',
  'Hotels.com',
  'Expedia.com',
  'Destinia',
  'Stayforlong.com',
  'Trip.com',
  'ebookers.ie',
  'Etrip',
  'ZenHotels.com',
  'Nustay.com' ]
got here 1
```

Which is the list of `providers`, I believe. **Notice** the selector used: `span[data-click-type='268']`.

Comment: I tried changing the selector, but the program still times out. Basically, I want a list of providers for every hotel that is displayed for that city. Right now, the program only prints a list of providers for one/two hotels and then the program crashes. Do you know how i can fix this?

Comment: And on the page where program times out, have you tried opening the console in Chromium and looking for the selector manually?